# Is there a way to align three columns in a grid layout proportional to a row?

Tags: android-layout, android, android-gridlayout

I have a grid layout with 6 columns.

For the top row i've given it colspan of 6. and for second row I've given each textView a colspan of 2.

I hoped this would make everything proportional. However, it looks like this:

[image]

But I want it to look something like this:

[image]

How can I make my three columns in second row propotional to the screen space such that first is on left, second is in center, and third is on right?

What I have so far is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="6"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded">

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Some Text"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_columnSpan="6"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        />



    <TextView
        android:text="96"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingRight="70dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="107"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingRight="70dp"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="62"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Text 1"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#ff565656"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Text 2"
        android:paddingRight="70dp"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#ff565656"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Text 3"
        android:textColor="#ff565656"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've manage to get something similar to what you posted. I am using a View hack though to get that subtle divider.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/element_bg"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="4" >

    <!-- Row 1 -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Some Text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- Row 2 -->

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <!-- Row 3 -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- Column 1 -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/row_padding" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="107"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tweets"
                android:textColor="#ff565656"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <!-- Column 2 -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/row_padding" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="96"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Following"
                android:textColor="#ff565656"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <!-- Column 3 -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/row_padding" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="56"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Followers"
                android:textColor="#ff565656"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Row 4 -->

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</GridLayout>
```

element_bg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    <corners android:radius="4dp" />

</shape>
```

Alternatively, you can try normal borders (easier to handle):

border.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
   <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
   <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
</shape>
```

dimens.xml. You can adjust the padding value as you like.

```
<resources>

    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="row_padding">15dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

For this last one, you might get elements to overlap their border, try some margin in those cases.

On a side note, you might want to use TableLayout as GridLayout can only be used from API 14+ and you cannot get this "space excess" to work with it unless you use a LinearLayout like I did to hack into weight property. 
"In general, it is not therefore possible to configure a GridLayout to distribute excess space between multiple components. [...] For complete control over excess space distribution in a row or column; use a LinearLayout subview to hold the components in the associated cell group." -http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html 

Tables - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html

Comment: Where is `@drawable/row_padding` coming from?

Comment: Sorry for the huge delay. @dimen/row_padding you mean, it's a simple dimen file used in Android resources /res/values/dimens.xml. It's essentially a file to save dimensions used in different views accross your app. I edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

One option that would certainly work would be to put each TextView inside a LinearLayout that has an attribute android:layout_weight="1" and that would automatically assign equal space to each LinearLayout (and hence each corresponding TextView).

Although, I cannot say for certain, the other option would be to directly add the attribute android:layout_weight="1" to each TextView - I think it should work but I haven't used this before. I'd be interested to see if this works as well.